# Meaning of `x_List`

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

What does `x_List` mean? I've seen many people use it but can't seem to find it in any of the Mathematica documentation.

An example:

```
DeleteCases[expVars, Null] //. {x_List} :> x
```

What is happening in that RuleDelayed expression?

Comment: It stands for any expression with head List. It seems the rule replaces a nested list by the inner one. You can find the answer in the documentation on Patterns.

Comment: Then please check with [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html).

Comment: Look at `{{{{Array[a, 5]}}}} //. {x_List} :> x`

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `_List` matches any expression with head `List`.

Recommended reading:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html
- [`Blank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)  (`_h` or `Blank[h]` can stand for any expression with head `h`.)